# Issues with PHP strtotime function rolling back one month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date stored in MySQL as 2012-11-00 and I am trying to convert it so I can format it properly on a PHP page. When I use the following I always end up getting one month behind. So if the date in MySQL is 2012-11-00 then the result from PHP is Oct 2012.

```
date("M Y", strtotime($resVal['dateField']))
```

Any thoughts as to why it does this?

Answer (score 2):

## #1.

Why dont you have dates saved as `2012-11-01`?

Because `2012-11-00` is "invalid", so for PHP that date is equal to `2012-10-31`.

## #2.

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` which can handle your (strange) format with ease:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-|??', '2012-11-00')->format('M Y');
```

will return `Nov 2012`

## #3.

Format date in MySQL with [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%b %Y')
FROM table
```

Comment: +1 for `DateTime::createFromFormat()`: -1 for doing it wrong.

Comment: @salathe: tnx for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Save the date as "2012-11-01", since 2012-11-00 is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

2012-11-00 is not a valid date
2012-11-01 is a date...
So probably it is rounding to 2012-10-31